# Convert patterns to CSS?

Tags: svg

In my SVG image I have a number of patterns such as this in the `defs` section:

```
        <pattern id="pat01" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="8px" height="8px"><image xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAgAAAAICAAAAADhZOFXAAAACXBIWXMAAAsSAAALEgHS3X78AAAAE0lEQVQImWP4vx8CGaD0fwayRADXsTfBHa7CGAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" x="0" y="0" width="8px" height="8px" /></pattern>
```

They work fine, but is there any way I can put them into a CSS stylesheet instead of the SVG document?

Or, can I store some of the stuff in my `defs` into an external file and then load them into the main SVG document?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the PNG image that is referenced in the pattern externally, or you can reference a [paint server](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/painting.html#SpecifyingPaint) that is part of an external file, i. e. file `paint.svg`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <!-- no need for a <defs> here, <pattern> is never rendered directly -->
    <pattern id="pat01" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="8px" height="8px">
        <image xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAgAAAAICAAAAADhZOFXAAAACXBIWXMAAAsSAAALEgHS3X78AAAAE0lEQVQImWP4vx8CGaD0fwayRADXsTfBHa7CGAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=="
              x="0" y="0" width="8px" height="8px" />
    </pattern>
</svg>
```

can be referenced by another `image.svg`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 800 600" width="800" height="600">
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" style="fill:url(paint.svg#pat01);" />
</svg>
```

Defining the pattern in CSS without referencing a SVG `<pattern>` element does not work.

At some time in the future, you might be able to set the `fill` property to an image and [repeat it](https://drafts.fxtf.org/fill-stroke-3/#fill-repeat) like a HTML `background-image`, but there are no implementations yet.